# How to downgrade or roll back AWS AFT ver after upgrading AWS AFT

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm planning to upgrade AWS Control Tower Account Factory for Terraform (AFT) by following a command

```
terraform get -update
```

Before upgrading, I would like to know how to downgrade or roll back AWS AFT ver after upgrading AWS AFT to move back previous environment.

I've been looking for a procedure to downgrade or rollback AFT but I cannot.

Comment: What are you trying to downgrade actually? A module? A provider version?

Comment: @MarkoE  it's both terraform and provider. Actually I'm planning to upgrade AFT from 1.6.7 to 1.11.1(latest). then, about my upgrading, I think that I need to upgrade both terraform and aws provider.